# TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED at Codeforces 558E

Tags: c++

I am beginner in the programming field and I have started to solve problems on Codeforces and this is my first problem on it and when I submit this problem solution [A Simple Task](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/558/E) with this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void swapchar(char &x, char &y)
{
char temp;
temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
}
void main()
{
string s;
long n, q;
long i, j;
bool k;
cin >> n >> q;
cin >> s;
for (int x = 0; x<q; x++)
{
    cin >> i >> j >> k;
    if (i<1 || j<1 || i>n || j>n)
        break;
    if (k == 1)
    {
        for (int u = i - 1; u < j; u++)
        {
            for (int v = u + 1; v < j; v++)
            {
                if (s[u] > s[v])
                    swapchar(s[u], s[v]);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (k == 0)
        for (int u = i - 1; u < j; u++)
        {
            for (int v = u + 1; v < j; v++)
            {
                if (s[u] < s[v])
                    swapchar(s[u], s[v]);
            }
        }
}
cout << s << endl;
}
```

then the codeforces' output is :-

```
Time limit exceeded on test 6
```

and when i searched about what it is the test 6 i found :-

```
Test: #6, time: 5000 ms., memory: 12 KB, exit code: -1, checker exit code: 0, verdict: TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
```

Input

```
2256 44182

kanqevxwgecliptqmdsgnflqyohgtukphlbmjxndbtjqujuafxankfghlseytdwdviamqjscacuyrghriuaihxtyersgnyvigenpflwequgbdusnvlgplxjxkqhjbdvkmufpoirqueufblnnrnbhmcnvewzfdonwjgswuneimtykntwgrlfqlvkdblwjzplhffzqpopbjmvrjcxyzgxqhkjbrgdqnipsipexpoozphfrgzboiiiskawtbhegerhvknrzljclhnpokpazhspsmzeiujddlpfireoyjzriickcuwtbimxjbhunedcdgaabztczkzmahnriarzcmnkjrrfqkodxbpocmxjvutpqbmawcsghwxdidhmwbfxuqegpjtqfvaloycogvoxdtjotlknazaeofaxlomeywwlezlndhpjwbgpxgkvubropxffytucvlbhjugzqgglrezoqsrvwkdrbuehbjxtgobugghqrgbgacqi...
```

I don't know what does that problem mean and how to solve it 
Please explain and help me.

Comment: `TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` - Your code is too slow. They have a time limit set (5000ms according to your question), which your code exceeded.

Comment: Despite its name, this is NOT a simple task. It is too difficult for a beginner in my opinion.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly how i can do this

Comment: @MoatazMohamed For one you seem to be sorting it with a [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which got O(n^2) complexity. You might look into using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead which only got O(n log n) complexity.

Comment: Actually looking at it again it's closer to an selection sort than bubble sort, the O(n^2) time complexity of your sorting still remains though.

Comment: sorry @RaphaelMiedl but you mean that what i wrote is selection sort right ?
how to write bubble sort here ?

Comment: No, you should use the `std::sort` from the standard library that I linked. You sort first looked like bubble sort to me but is actually closer to selection sort. They are both O(n^2) and slower than the standard one qhich is only O(n log n).

Comment: how to use it ? @RaphaelMiedl

Comment: @MoatazMohamed sorry, went to lunch. Wrote an answer now that should get you up to test 9 and an idea on how to get further.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl no problem thank you

Comment: @MoatazMohamed If you're interested I added a lot more about how one could save time taking advantage of the input order to the end of my answer, it gives huge algorithm hints though so I'd recommend not to read it if you still want to try a bit more yourself.

Comment: @hlt Is that not obvious? For a competitive coder like OP, saying this is just useless and wasting everyone's time. Say something that is actually helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a selection sort (with a few superfluous swaps) that's O(n^2) complexity, try using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead. You don't have too much to change in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string s;
long n, q;
long i, j;
bool k;
cin >> n >> q;
cin >> s;
for (int x = 0; x<q; x++)
{
    cin >> i >> j >> k;
    if (i<1 || j<1 || i>n || j>n)
        break;
    if (k == 1)
    {
        std::sort(s.begin() + i-1,  s.begin() + j);
    }
    else if (k == 0)
        std::sort(s.begin() + i-1, s.begin() + j, std::greater<char>());
}
cout << s << endl;
}
```

`std::sort(s.begin() + i-1,  s.begin() + j);` sorts from `s.begin() + i-1` up to but not including`s.begin() + j`. The second just sorts in reverse order by using `>` (`std::greater`) instead of `<` for comparison. Note the `#include <algorithm>` for the `std::sort` and `#include <functional>` for `std::greater`.

Note that I got rid of your `swapchar` function since we don't need it anymore, I also changed the return type of `main` to `int` as it's supposed to be.

The above code manages to handle the test 6 that you had problems with but exceeds time limit for test 9 (I even tried some small other changes there).

To complete tests 9+ you're probably supposed to think a bit more about the problem and possible input, take for example the following sort queries:

```
20 57   1
89 950  1
57 100  0
57 100  1
1  9500 0
```

Here we'd do tons of useless sorting and I wouldn't be surprised if the 9th problem were to test if you identified this. First we sort the range [20, 57] and [89, 950] in ascending order, then we sort the range [57, 100] in descending order and resorting the same range in ascending order right afterwards overriding the first one completely. Lastly we sort the range [1, 9500] in descending order, overwriting all the previous sorts which we could have completely left out since they're overwritten anyways.

We could make use of the knowledge that later sorts **can** and likely **will** override previous ones. We could first save all the "sort queries" we were given and later start with the last one (since that one would override all previous ones anyways) and go in reverse order only sorting the ranges we haven't sorted yet. That way we can get rid of lots of useless sorting that we'd otherwise do even though we'd later overwrite it and speeding it up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use this code
'''C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void swapchar(char &x, char &y) {
    char temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main() {
    string s;
    long n, q;

    cin >> n >> q;
    cin >> s;

    for (int x = 0; x < q; x++) {
        long i, j;
        bool k;

        cin >> i >> j >> k;

        if (i < 1 || j < 1 || i > n || j > n)
            break;

        if (k == 1) {
            sort(s.begin() + i - 1, s.begin() + j);
        } else if (k == 0) {
            sort(s.begin() + i - 1, s.begin() + j, greater<char>());
        }
    }

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

'''